# lazy (non-buffered) processing of shell pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe, zsh

I'm trying to figure out how to perform the laziest possible processing of a standard UNIX shell pipeline.  For example, let's say I have a command which does some calculations and outputting along the way, but the calculations get more and more expensive so that the first few lines of output arrive quickly but then subsequent lines get slower.  If I'm only interested in the first few lines then I want to obtain those via [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), terminating the calculations ASAP before they get too expensive.

This can be achieved with a straight-forward shell pipeline, e.g.:

```
./expensive | head -n 2
```

However this does not work optimally.  Let's simulate the calculations with a script which gets exponentially slower:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=1
while true; do
    echo line $i
    sleep $(( i ** 4 ))
    i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

Now when I pipe this script through `head -n 2`, I observe the following:

- `line 1` is output.
- After sleeping one second, `line 2` is output.
- Despite `head -n 2` having already received two (`\n`-terminated) lines and exiting, `expensive` carries on running and now waits a further 16 seconds (`2 ** 4`) before completing, at which point the pipeline also completes.

Obviously this is not as lazy as desired, because ideally `expensive` would terminate as soon as the `head` process receives two lines.  However, this does not happen; IIUC it actually terminates after trying to write its *third* line, because at this point it tries to write to its `STDOUT` which is connected through a pipe to `STDIN` the `head` process which has already exited and is therefore no longer reading input from the pipe.  This causes `expensive` to receive a `SIGPIPE`, which causes the `bash` interpreter running the script to invoke its `SIGPIPE` handler which by default terminates running the script (although this can be changed via the `trap` command).

So the question is, how can I make it so that `expensive` quits *immediately* when `head` quits, not just when `expensive` tries to write its third line to a pipe which no longer has a listener at the other end?  Since the pipeline is constructed and managed by the interactive shell process I typed the `./expensive | head -n 2` command into, presumably that interactive shell is the place where any solution for this problem would lie, rather than in any modification of `expensive` or `head`?  Is there any native trick or extra utility which can construct pipelines with the behaviour I want?  Or maybe it's simply impossible to achieve what I want in `bash` or `zsh`, and the only way would be to write my own pipeline manager (e.g. in Ruby or Python) which spots when the reader terminates and immediately terminates the writer?

Comment: Aside: Ideally, `.sh` extensions should be used for shell *libraries* that can be sourced int any POSIX-compliant shell (`.bash` for libraries compatible only with bash, `.zsh` for libraries compatible with zsh). Using extensions for executable commands makes for trouble whenever they're rewritten to a different language -- now you need to update every caller to invoke a differently-named command, or you have a misleading name -- and it's misleading in any event to call a script with a `bash` shebang with a name implying that `sh` can invoke it.

Comment: Great point, thanks! I guess this comment comes from the fact that `$(( ))` is `bash`-specific and not POSIX-compliant?

Comment: Actually, `$(( ))` *is* POSIX-compliant -- it's only using `(( ))` to enter an arithmetic context without the result undergoing substitution that's a bashism -- but the `#!/bin/bash` shebang means you're getting two different interpreters (or an interpreter operating in different modes) depending on invocation.

Comment: Ah, gotcha - thanks!  I've dropped the `.sh` suffix from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you care about is foreground control, you can run `expensive` in a process substitution; it still blocks until it next tries to write, but `head` exits immediately (and your script's flow control can continue) after it's received its input

```
head -n 2 < <(exec ./expensive)
# expensive still runs 16 seconds in the background, but doesn't block your program
```

In bash 4.4, these store their PIDs in `$!` and allow process management in the same manner as other background processes.

```
# REQUIRES BASH 4.4 OR NEWER
exec {expensive_fd}< <(exec ./expensive); expensive_pid=$!
head -n 2 <&"$expensive_fd"  # read the content we want
exec {expensive_fd}<&-       # close the descriptor
kill "$expensive_pid"        # and kill the process
```

Another approach is a coprocess, which has the advantage of only requiring bash 4.0:

```
# magic: store stdin and stdout FDs in an array named "expensive", and PID in expensive_PID
coproc expensive { exec ./expensive }

# read two lines from input FD...
head -n 2 <&"${expensive[0]}"

# ...and kill the process.
kill "$expensive_PID"
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! However I can't get the `$!` trick working; with bash 4.4.12(1)-release, `$!` does not get set to anything.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using a MacPorts build of 4.4.12(1) and it's working happily here as a copy-and-paste from the answer. Might I ask your platform?

Comment: openSUSE Leap 42.2, also copy-and-pasted.

Comment: Err. OpenSUSE 42.2 appears to ship with bash 4.3.42(1)-release (at least, the public-repo Docker images do). That is to say: `$ docker run opensuse:42.2 bash -c 'echo "$BASH_VERSION"'` emits as output `4.3.42(1)-release`.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, ...I think I've reproduced your problem and incorporated a fix. As a single-line reproducer for the working form: `docker run bash:4.4 bash -c 'expensive() { i=1; while true; do echo "line $i"; sleep $(( i ** 4 )); i=$(( i + 1 )); done; }; exec 3< <(expensive); expensive_pid=$!; head -n 2 <&3; kill "$expensive_pid"'`

Comment: I'm not using the standard bash from 42.2; I'm using [the version from the `shells` project on OBS](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/shells/bash) which is 4.4.12(1) as previously stated. But the new version of your solution does indeed work, although I have no idea why! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer with a POSIX shell in mind.

What you can do is use a fifo instead of a pipe and kill the first link the moment the second finishes.

If the expensive process is a leaf process or if it takes care of killing its children, you can use a simple kill. If it's a process-spawning shell script, you should run it in a process group (doable with `set -m`) and kill it with a process-group kill.

Example code:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
expensive()
{
    i=1
    while true; do
        echo line $i
        sleep 0.$i     #sped it up a little
        echo >&2 slept 
        i=$(( i+1 ))
    done
}
echo >&2 NORMAL
expensive | head -n2
#line 1
#slept
#line 2
#slept

echo >&2 SPED-UP
mkfifo pipe
exec 3<>pipe 
rm pipe
set -m; expensive  >&3 & set +m
<&3 head -n 2
kill -- -$!
#line 1
#slept
#line 2
```

If you run this, the second run should not have the second `slept` line, meaning the first link was killed the moment `head` finished, not when the first link tried to output after `head` was finished.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Although I've noticed that `bash` does its own strange buffering (or maybe just coalescing of output from its built-in `echo` command), so I'd be a little wary of trusting the `slept` output lines over a `sleep` with a big enough interval to be noticeable.